# How to add TableFooterView in IOS 5 Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, storyboard

How to I add a tablefooterview in the same way as adding a tableheader view in iOS 5 StoryBoard, as outline in this page:

[Table Header Views in StoryBoards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards)

It does not seem to work easily. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this in the meantime?