# Using Storyboards, how to put a UIView at top of UITableView in UITableViewController

Tags: xcode4, uitableview, uistoryboard

Using XCode 4 and Storyboards, I want to have a UIView (with labels and textfields) on the top half of a UITableViewController, and a custom cell in the UITableView on the bottom half of the UITableViewController.

When I place a UIView on the UITableViewController, it goes to the top of the scene as expected; when I add the UITableViewCell, it also goes to the top of the scene, covering the UIView.  There appears to be no way to resize either view.

I have looked at the "tableHeaderView", but can't find any example of how to implement it, assuming it will do what I want.

How do I accomplish having a UIView on top and custom UITableViewCells below on the lower half of a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found on this SO question:  [Table Header Views in StoryBoards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards)

I tried it and it indeed did what I wanted it to do.  Thank you Mr. Rogers!