# Header in storyboard for UITableViewController does not "stick"

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that is in a storyboard. I want to add a header to it so I followed the instructions in the following post. I dragged a UIView up on top, and on top of that i dragged a couple of images.

[Table Header Views in StoryBoards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards)

Now that seemed to work fine, but the header scrolls along with the entries in table cells when i scroll up. Also, they seem to scroll underneath the time and battery indicator...not sure why that is.

So in the comments of that post i saw that you need to implement the following function to return the UiView to get it to "stick". The only way I saw how to get the UiView from the storyboard was to set the tag and then look it up, also shown below.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section.
{
     int tagNumber = 2; 
     UIView *headerView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:tagNumber];
     return headerView;
}
```

The issue with all of this is the header still scrolls. How can i get the header view to just stay on top?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376697/how-to-make-uitable-header-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-when-using-storyboards

Comment: Thanks kaszas, i tried that but the solution seems to just create a new view with a text field and returns that. I'd like to use the one drawn in my storyboard.

Comment: Did you every figure out how to do this?

Comment: I figured it out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23717919/1438339