# UITableView Header and footer indent during edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with three Cell Prototypes in the storyboard, I use one cell in the header section, one for the normal table rows and another for the table footer.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Header";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //some personalization
    return cell;
}
```

My problem is whenever i enter in the edit mode of the tableview the header and footer are moving to the left, like the cell that is current editing.

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}
```

[image: before]

In edit mode:

[image: after]

Any solution or hints?
Neither the last XCode update fixed it.

Thank you

Comment: I posted the code on how I created the header and activated the edit mode.

Comment: Did you change the animation or adjust the frame? Hope more detail.

Comment: Nothing else. Could the problem be I'm using a UITableViewCell for Header and not a UIView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. Basically I had to create a UIView and use that in as My header / footer, and not use a UITableViewCell.

Thanks to

[Table Header Views in StoryBoards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards)
and

[Stick UITableView header view to top when creating header in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713883/stick-uitableview-header-view-to-top-when-creating-header-in-storyboard/23717919#23717919)

Answer (score 4):

Along the way I found out that it's perfectly fine using a `tableViewCell`, you just return the cell `contentView` and the indention for the header while editing is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue of "moving" headers with creating a header with a UIView instead of UITableViewCell. You can do it by simply dragging a UIView out to the UITableView it will place it right above/between prototype cells. Then you can treat it as and view in Interface Builder. You can create a controller for it, but imho it is quicker and easier to give it a `tag` and then use `tableView.viewWithTag(tag)`. Hope it helps!