# UITableView floating view like iPhone Maps app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the iOS 6 Maps App, when looking at the details for a location, there is a control that acts like a `UISegmentedControl`. It has 3 "tabs": 'Info', 'Reviews', and 'Photos'.

This control scrolls up and down when the picture is visible, but becomes anchored to the top of the screen and floats when scrolling down more. These pictures may help clarify what I'm trying to state:

[image: first]
[image: second]
[image: third]

Any tips on how I can create this behavior on my own UITableView? The tableview needs to be of the `Grouped` style, and I need to have multiple sections, so using the Section Header View is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

make use of the `UITableView's tableHeaderView` property to add your segmented control.

`MapView` and `TableView` should be siblings, and added as a subviews to a scrollView.

The `tableView.frame.size.height` should be what you see in the image2 (parentViewHeight-navBarHeight)

```
scrollView.frame.size.height = tableView.frame.size.height

scrollView.contentSize.height = tableView.frame.size.height + mapView.frame.size.height
```

this should be enough to get the effect you are trying to do. let me know if you have any issues with it.

PS: mapView is just a place holder I assumed for the view you see above the segmented control. you can replace it with any view you want. I am assuming you know how to do the grouped tableView part of these views.

Comment: This was my initial idea as well; however, selection inside the `UITableView` would stop working once it was inside a `UIScrollView`. Furthermore, you didn't state how I could get the floating effect I wanted.

Nevertheless, upvoted for taking a good stab at the problem!

Comment: My idea was that the tableViewHeader (not the section header) would stay static, once the scrollview scrolled all the way by swiping up, after which the tableView (other than the tableView header) should scroll. what do you mean by selection would stop working? didSelectRow is not getting called?

Comment: I tried exactly as you said, just now. Didn't work :(. I want the mapView to scroll away while the segmented control would become anchored after scrolling down past a certain point. In your example, the segmented control were part of the tableview, so it disappeared once I scrolled down enough on the tableview. Since the tableview itself is a scroll view, the fact that it is inside a scrollview didn't do anything.

I was able to fix the didSelectRow not being called, so disregard that part.

Comment: I think you may have to use a scrollViewDidScroll delegate method, check for the scrollview offset and enable/disable tableView scrolling based on the offset.     theTableView.scrollEnabled = theScrollView.contentOffset.y > theTableView.frame.origin.y; will try this in a test project some time this week and let you know if I can help.

Comment: I can post my test project on github real quick, it may be faster. :) hold on ...

Comment: why are you doing this? - (UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return (UIScrollView *) self.view;
}

Comment: convenience method for casting self.view into a UIScrollView, since self.view is a UIView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23524/discussion-between-calvinbhai-and-orryowr)

Comment: How did you end up accomplishing this?