# How to use a view defined in a Storyboard for viewForHeaderInSection?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, ios7, uistoryboard

**UPDATE:** I ended up doing it with a nib file. See Josh Justice's answer here on how to go about the process of setting up the nib (File -> New File -> User Interface -> View) for a header view. It's not straightforward: [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)

---

I'm trying to define a `UIView` in my Storyboard and use it as a layout for my `UITableView` header. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards) as a guide, but can't seem to get it working (ios7). I've tried using `UIImageView` as shown in the post, as well as a regular `UIView` but no luck. One thing I don't understand is that I can create a new `UIView`, like below, and set the background color easily enough, but if I load the view out of the storyboard using the tag, I can't seem to change the background and it only shows up gray.  What am I doing wrong here?! I guess I can create the entire Header in code but it seems like there is something I'm missing here.

[image]

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   // doing it this way, the header stays positioned
   // and visible no matter where the table is scrolled
   // UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];

   // pulling the view out of the storyboard doesn't seem to work
   // can't change bgcolor on this view.. 
   UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:200];

   // this only changes the background color when the view is created
   // with initWithFrame.. above. Otherwise it's just gray.
   [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:.7 blue:.9 alpha:1]];
   return (v);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That post is for the Header of the table view and not for the hear on every section of the table view.

What you are trying to do has to be done by creating the view programmatically or in a separate nib file.