# How to segue from UITableView header?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I need to push another `UIViewController` when click the `UITableView` header, I try to do it in the storyboard but I can't Ctrl drag from the `UITableView` header ?

Is it possible to segue from `UITableView` header ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag a UIButton to the top of the TableView to set it as the header and then control drag from the button to make your segue.

EDIT: You can drag any type of view to the header that has some sort of onTouchDown outlet but I figured a button would be the simplest for demonstration purposes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841167/table-header-views-in-storyboards for more details on the dragging in a header view for anyone who might not be aware.