# Avoid header to scroll in in UITableView with UITableViewStylePlain in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

Hi i have one plain table view. On top there is header ..i want to scroll only cells not header ..is any solution 
I also see this but it is not working [Is it possible to disable floating headers in UITableView with UITableViewStylePlain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074006/is-it-possible-to-disable-floating-headers-in-uitableview-with-uitableviewstylep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this as mention babyPanda like you have to take one `UIView` and `UItableview` into Your XIB.

Like bellow image"-

[image]

i just create a Demo for you please check bellow link and try, Hope its helps you

http://www.sendspace.com/file/xguycm

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative (might not be called a "solution"), is to make the view of headers the first cell in a section.

Note: If you try to fix header of the first section, then the only possible method might be, making it a view, whose frame is right above the table view.