# How to stop scrolling of row of UITableView inside of header UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When I am scrolling vertically row is going inside of headerview of table, how will change to stop going of row inside of header of UITableView. I have some important view which should show always top of UITableView and if user scroll it should hide as row hides.

Going row in top header should also go on top.

I mean it should show attaching headerview with first row.

Comment: header should also go up as user scroll?

Comment: Yes..exactly..same as row is going up..

Comment: rewrite your question properly. cant understand exactly what you want

Comment: then add 1 extra cell on top. if you put header view it wont go as row.

Comment: Do you mean section headers or the table header?

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074006/is-it-possible-to-disable-floating-headers-in-uitableview-with-uitableviewstylep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074006/is-it-possible-to-disable-floating-headers-in-uitableview-with-uitableviewstylep)

Comment: This question is already discussed here: [Change Default Scrolling Behavior of UITableView Section Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664781/change-default-scrolling-behavior-of-uitableview-section-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep `numberOfCell`

```
array.count+1
```

In cellForRow method

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    //create your cell as header and return
}
else
{
     //return normal cells
}
```

Comment: hmmm..ok.. that I was thinking to do.. but I thought if there would be any function which disabled the scrolling of rows inside of section...accepting this answer..

Comment: to make more clean code you can add two sections. in section 0 add one cell and in section 1 add others. njoy coding