# ios - First section of tableView not moving with the rest of tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to iOS programming so maybe my question is dumb but I have a tableView which doesn't bounce and when I scroll downwards the first section of my tableView stays in place while the section and all the content scrolls.

I don't know what to do in order to have the first section moving as well...

Edit : Actually it's the first header that doesn't move with the rest.

Comment: OK,, put some relevant code here :)

Comment: are you sure the first section isn't a header ?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant the first header. It's the header that don't move...

Comment: It is the default behavior. Section headers stick to the top of the screen by default until you jump to the next section. This answer suggests how to disable it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4295687/1152596

Comment: And can someone tell me why when I scroll the cells go over the first header ?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this is happening, from what i've seen is because your first, cell will be more appropriate word, instead of section, is because it is a header of the section,if i'm wrong, some code will be helpful