# how iPhone table view current section heading "sticks" to the top

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How iPhone table view current section heading "sticks" to the top until the next heading "pushes" it out of the view like many iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior of Plain UITableView. The same happens with the footer view as well. it sticks to the bottom. If you want to avoid this, you have to customize some of your cells to look like section headers

Comment: You can also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664781/change-default-scrolling-behavior-of-uitableview-section-header