# Any way to make table view section title line fixed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

[image]

As shown in pic, when trying slide table up, section title B line will move up as well, but will keep on top of screen until next section title line arrive to top of screen.

Is there anyway to let the section title line move as normal table cell, don't stay on the top of screen until next section title line arrived？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know of how you would do this using the normal sections, you could fake it by adding extra cells to the table view which represent section headers though

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer for this already here:

[Change Default Scrolling Behavior of UITableView Section Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664781/change-default-scrolling-behavior-of-uitableview-section-header)

Basically, use grouped style for the table and then provide your own UIViews for the table headers and cells to customise the look of them.