# UITableView: anchor section header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with one section and a header. The problem is that when I scroll down beyond the contents of the table, the header is pulled down along with the cells. I would like it to stay at the top of the view. I tried the suggestion on this post,

[Change Default Scrolling Behavior of UITableView Section Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664781/change-default-scrolling-behavior-of-uitableview-section-header)

using the footer of a zero-row section as the header, but it still isn't anchored. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a UITableViewController?  If you are using a UIViewController that contains a UITableView you could just add a UIView above the UITableView.

You could also add the UIView on top of the UITableView and add an alpha gradient to make it look more similar to a regular UITableView section header.

Comment: I'm trying this right now but the table view fills the whole view, even if I set a new frame. Is there any way to restrict this?

Comment: I think you're probably using a UITableViewController if you can not change the frame.  Please check.  If you are then you will need to switch to a UIViewController with a UITableView inside of it.  The UITableViewController is very restrictive.

Comment: I am using a UIViewController with a UIView and UITableViewController. I eventually got it work by doing everything programmatically, but I believe the table view fills the screen regardless of what view controller you're using if loaded from a nib.

Comment: You should not add a **UITableViewController** to a UIViewController.  You should try a **UITableView** in the UIViewController instead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say UITableView.