# Expandable UITableView Sticking

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an expandable UITableView.  It works fine but the issue I am running into is when a given row is expanded and the user scrolls up, the opened section row scrolls up to the top of the visible table and stick.

[image: The section row expands showing the detail material]

In the below image, the detail row material and the succeeding section rows scroll OVER the opened section row.

[image: Here is the succeeding section scrolling over the opened section row.]

I would expect that the section row would scroll off the top of the visible table view.

Am I missing something that would allow the section row to scroll up rather than stick?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 7. Keep UITableView section header from sticking on top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014775/ios-7-keep-uitableview-section-header-from-sticking-on-top)

Comment: That was it, I knew it was something stupid that I forgot to set.  Need to set the UITableView style to Grouped.