# Make a TableHeaderView not scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, cells, tableheader

I made a TableView, with prototypes cells; in first position of the tableView I made this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0
    {
        let view : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 140))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(populateView())
        //populateView() is a method by which I programmatically made all object in the view (label, images, textView)
        return view
    }
    else
    {
        return nil
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    if section == 0
    {
        return 140
    } else
    {
        return 0
    }
}
```

and the result is this (it's a test): 
[image: screenshot]

Now I'd like to make the TableHeaderView not scrolling with the tableView; I made tableView style as plain; and I found this [Change Default Scrolling Behavior of UITableView Section Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664781/change-default-scrolling-behavior-of-uitableview-section-header) and this https://corecocoa.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/how-to-disable-floating-header-in-uitableview/ but I don't know Objective-c (I am swift programmer from just 6 months). can anyone solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely use UIViewController with UITableView and custom view above it (see below).

[image]

Or if you want to use UITableViewController (which brings some extra features), you can embed it under the header using container view.

[image]

Comment: Well maybe the first option is more simple. But if you want to use UITableViewControllers, then you can basically pass the information to the tableViewController when loaded – using  either "self.childViewControllers.first" or get pointer to the embedded UITableViewController in the "performSegue:" method. (embedding controllers is just a special kind of segue)

Comment: I fail to see how this answer improves on the one I gave 2 hours earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use a `UIViewController`, rather than a `UITableViewController`. A table view controller will claim the whole `view` and there is no space above.

Instead, you have to use a `UIViewController`, add a subview as the header, and add a `UITableView` also as a subview. You populate and interact with it by explicitly including the data source and delegate protocols.

```
class HeaderTableViewController : UIViewController, 
                                  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```