# Changing default behaviour of the UITableview to move section headers under the navigation bar (Sample included)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios-autolayout

I am developing a User Profile page somewhat similar to Twitter in which I am using a plain style tableview with user image in table view header & normal section headers.
I want my tableview to start from (0,0) point behind the transparent navigation bar so that user image can be seen behind the navigation bar.

Also, I want to lock the section header underneath navigation bar which I am successfully able to do by constraints. Now when I scroll up and next section headers gets locked underneath Nav bar **but at the same time first section header appears to go behind the transparent Nav bar which looks odd.**

Any one could help like how can I fix this to make the last section header to go under the Nav bar not behind it.

**Removed two screenshots depicting the issues & added the sample**

Sample Link :- https://github.com/GauravTechbirds/headerlock

Actual Repo :- https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/twitterprofilepage

Comment: See related question on your right side of question, already answered. For Example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664781/change-default-scrolling-behavior-of-uitableview-section-header?rq=1

Comment: All this stuff on right side is very old i.e back to 2009-2010 when auto layout and plain/grouped stuff was not even introduced, though i tried everything mentioned in those answers, but no success. :-(

Comment: Hey I have added the sample with the exact issue,hope if you could help. Thanks~